# Parse method name from call

Tags: runtime

I have a `Call` which looks like:

```
Call::TokenWrapperHandler(Call::execute_wrapping_fee_proposal { r_id: [101, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 101, 95, 119, 114, 97, 112, 112, 105, 110, 103, 95, 102, 101, 101, 95, 112, 114, 111, 112, 111, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5], wrapping_fee_percent: 5, into_pool_share_id: 1 })
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to parse out the method name, namely `execute_wrapping_fee_proposal`, from it?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable can help you get the text of a type if it is for debug purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not for debug purposes.

Comment: Are you trying to parse that as a string?(that would be weird) all the info you need is in the metadata of the chain

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the call name you are looking for is NOT encoded in the call data.

Call encoding in Substrate is composed of two bytes:

1. First byte will represent the Pallet index where the call is.
2. Second byte will represent the Call index of the call.

So let's assume you are looking for the encoded call of the Balances `transfer` call:

First you look at your `construct_runtime!` to see how the pallets are indexed for your runtime:

```
// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
        TemplateModule: pallet_template,
    }
);
```

Here we can see that the `Balances` pallet has index 5 (starting from 0).

Then we look at the `Balances` pallet to see which call index the `transfer` call is, and as of writing this post, it is the very first call: index 0;

So the encoded version of `pallet_balances::Call::transfer` will be `0x0500`.

So yeah, without the metadata of the chain, you will not be able to work backwards here to find the actual method name. However, this is exactly what the runtime metadata is used for, so you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `Call` in your Runtime, you can use [`GetCallMetadata::get_call_metadata()`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.GetCallMetadata.html#tymethod.get_call_metadata) and then use the [`CallMetadata::function_name`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/traits/struct.CallMetadata.html#structfield.function_name) to get the name you are searching for.