# Implement utility.batch using @substrate/txwrapper-polkadot

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, polkadot-js-extension, txwrapper

I am trying to implement batch transactions alongside the normal balances.transfer. Because of several reasons (constructing transaction more than one stage and polkadot lib is not helping there) i am using `@substrate/txwrapper-polkadot` methods.balances.transfer and now i am trying methods.utility.batchAll. However i am facing something weird.

For transfer i used this:

```
    const unsigned = methods.balances.transfer(
      {
        dest: toAddress,
        value,
      },
      {
        address: account.address,
        blockHash,
        blockNumber,
        eraPeriod: 64,
        genesisHash,
        metadataRpc,
        nonce,
        specVersion,
        tip,
        transactionVersion,
      },
      {
        metadataRpc,
        registry,
      },
    );
```

This function takes 3 parameter:
`function transfer(args: BalancesTransferArgs, info: BaseTxInfo, options: OptionsWithMeta): UnsignedTransaction`

This args: BalancesTransferArgs takes `dest` and `value`.

utility.batch however uses `UtilityBatch` as args :

```
    calls: ({
        callIndex?: string;
        args?: string;
    } | string)[];
```

I tried to use same args part (first part of the unsigned that i wrote up there) of batch transfer from another transaction which i get with `api.rpc.chain.getBlock`:

`[{"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"1w3QEceeCRN2Rv3GfUohY6yTpRUoo4BRdQ2b7s2jTgK4q4y"},"value":142062126800}}, {"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"157xqEJLZDUmhc1RFvUDitKP3ygFDsJeXHifJw1Th2Pn7khH"},"value":130297371500}}, {"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"13qkt6YBJyqzh4jdtJ4dooJDsTgAGKWoM2MwHreWN7LpYEHc"},"value":428418876800}}, {"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"15sSvgpSsonimLWpHv7ZUhyNoXjd4VNMm2wpDeDVtcp2W58"},"value":999200000000}}, {"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"13ee8dYeLBR7iaGEcSjbaC7ooRw2U5iSNexdFdTEo4VBVvVN"},"value":150723408800}}, {"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"1555Ub7YF1tiyDv7JzUNToVjbUzAoK6X8k9RGGUYMK7ZUwAk"},"value":14200000000}}]`

but its not accepting parameter as object like this because it wants it as string and i really couldn't figure  what should i put there.

And what is callIndex? What it should be?

Can Anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it will be helpful for you to check the [batchAll example](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadotBatchAll/src/polkadotBatchAll.ts) in the txwrapper-core repository. It uses `transferKeepAlive` and `batchAll` but the concept is basically the same.

In this example you will notice that :

1. First the const [txMethods](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/91b5b614e64b725c59dd9558c47f8905b72aa2d2/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadotBatchAll/src/polkadotBatchAll.ts#L136) is defined where [txInfo.method](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/91b5b614e64b725c59dd9558c47f8905b72aa2d2/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadotBatchAll/src/polkadotBatchAll.ts#L152) (the `method` from the `UnsignedTransaction`) is returned.
2. Then in the `calls` argument of `utility.batchAll` this [txMethods](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/91b5b614e64b725c59dd9558c47f8905b72aa2d2/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadotBatchAll/src/polkadotBatchAll.ts#L160) is passed.

This will work because the `calls` argument of `batch` or `batchAll` can be an array of `UnsignedTransaction.method` as mentioned in [utility.batch](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-substrate/src/methods/utility/batch.ts#L12L15) and also in the comment above the [utility.batchAll call](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadotBatchAll/src/polkadotBatchAll.ts#L155L157) in the example.

Regarding your question on what `callIndex` is, you can check the following:

- This [post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/98/234) from Shawn Tabrizi where he explains how calls are encoded.
- Check some examples of call indices from the `Balances` pallet in Substrate :

  - `transfer` call with [call index 0](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L284)
  - `set_balance` call with [call index 1](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L310)
- Important to keep in mind that these indices can change between runtime upgrades (as mentioned also by Jaco [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4496#issuecomment-1020854518) in more detail)

Comment: Thank you. Although I looked at the normal transfer from there, I completely forgot about the existence of the example part. Still missing staking tho.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "missing staking"? If it is not very closely related to this question maybe you would like to create another question ?